# Industries interconnections data sets

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request

I'm looking for the data source that describes how the industries related to each other via consume/produce cycle.
Any data source that could help me build chains like in the following example:

*Bauxite ore > (consumed by) aluminum industry  (produce) >  aluminum > (consumed by) aerospace*

Comment: If you just want to identify particular supply chains, [IBISWorld Industry Reports](https://my.ibisworld.com/) would typically have a section on that. For example, here's one involving [the US aluminum industry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr2y7.png). This is not the kind of "data" in the usual sense, though.

Comment: @HerrK. thank you for your link. I would like as many as possible across all economy. Aluminum is just an example :)

Comment: This sounds like Input-Output Analysis, where you have  Outputs=[Some Matrix]*Inputs. Many countries' statistical agencies have the matrix  (unfortunately I personally don't know any sources).

Answer (score 1):

Most OECD countries have Input-Output Account tables as part of their economic statistics publications. For the U.S., you can find them here at the [BEA's website](https://www.bea.gov/data/industries/input-output-accounts-data). I'm not sure that they will be as detailed as you hope, however.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I want something like this but either more granular or tables with more industries.